# Blueprint / Yii table colors

Tags: css, yii, blueprint-css

I am having two issues similar to the question previously posed on table colors with Blueprint CSS (alternating rows):

1. I was able to override the zebra colors by changing both the th, td, caption to the same color as the tbody tr:nth child(even).  However, when I do that, I lose the "highlighted" color change when you roll the cursor over the table results.
2. I cannot change the table header color/fonts.  I have added color and background to the table, th, thead th and nothing changes.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the widget with the table add the 'css' parameter - it should be pointing at .css style.
Default style shouldn't even load if you specify custom style that you want to be used with table.

Example:

```
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'cssFile' => Yii::app()->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/css/yiiTableStyle.css',
            'dataProvider'=>$provider,
            'columns'=>array(
                'some_name::Name'
            )
        ));
```